# How do I change the margins on Quill.js toolbar?

Tags: html, css, quill

I'm building a webpage that allows my users the ability to enter rich text and ultimately upload that rich text to my database. I am using [Quill.js](https://quilljs.com/) as my rich text editor via the Quill CDN. I have setup Quill successfully. The Quill editor and toolbar containers are setup as so:

```
<div class="quill-toolbar" id="toolbar" style="margin-left: 50px; margin-right: 50px"></div>
<div class="quill-editor" id="editor" style="margin-left: 50px; margin-right: 50px"></div>
```

I have also written a script to initialize Quill.js with the "snow" themed editor enabled. That script is below:

```
<script>
        var FontAttributor = Quill.import('formats/font');
        FontAttributor.whitelist = [
            'sans-serif', 'sofia', 'slabo', 'roboto', 'inconsolata', 'ubuntu'
        ];

        Quill.register(FontAttributor, true);

        var toolbarOptions = [
            ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike'],
            [{ 'size': ['small', false, 'large', 'huge'] }],
            [{ 'font': [] }],
            [{ 'align': [] }],
            [{ 'color': [] }, { 'background': [] }],
            [{ 'list': 'ordered' }, { 'list': 'bullet' }],
            [{ 'script': 'sub' }, { 'script': 'super' }],
            [{ 'indent': '-1' }, { 'indent': '+1' }],
            ['link', 'image', 'video', 'formula'],
        ];

        var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
            modules: {
                toolbar: toolbarOptions,
            },
            placeholder: 'Start writing...',
            theme: 'snow'
        });\
</script>
```

My struggle appears when I try to position the Quill toolbar properly. Using inline CSS, I was able to position the Quill editor in the center of the screen with 50 pixel margins, like you saw when I setup the toolbar and editor containers: `style="margin-left: 50px; margin-right: 50px"`. However, I am unable to do the same with the Quill toolbar.

How can I setup the toolbar so it has 50 pixel margins on each side of the toolbar as well as the editor?

*Status Update*

I have continued to experiment with CSS changes to add margins to the toolbar. The easiest solution I could find was to set margins to the `<body>` for the page. However, now I am having a problem with my navigation bar. The `<body>` appears like this `<body style="margin-left: 50px">`. However, the navigation bar is now misplaced, and if I add a negative margin like this: `<div class="topnav" style="margin-left: -50px">`, their is a gap on the right side of the navigation bar. Why is this happening. It changing the margins of the `<body>` the best solution?